# How handle java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error in android?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am taking a picture through my device in my app and saving that on to the server

im using samsung note 2

but I'm getting this error

```
10-31 20:34:06.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12985): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-5431
10-31 20:34:06.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12985): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
10-31 20:34:06.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12985):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
10-31 20:34:06.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12985):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:640)
10-31 20:34:06.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12985):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:586)
10-31 20:34:06.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12985):    at com.winit.dropbox.MainScreen.flip(MainScreen.java:1241)
10-31 20:34:06.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12985):    at com.winit.dropbox.MainScreen$DropBoxUploader.run(MainScreen.java:1166)
10-31 20:34:06.759: E/AndroidRuntime(12985):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

the code points to this line,

```
        Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), m, false);
```

while m is

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
```

EDIT: I've removed the matrix during create bitmap for now, but now I'm facing problem while resizing the image taken through the android device, im using

```
bmp = BitmapsUtiles.getResizedBmp(bmp, AppConstants.DEVICE_WIDTH, AppConstants.DEVICE_HEIGHT);
```

but still it is not working, can you please point it out what am i doing wrong while resizing???

Comment: Please have a look at the developer site: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: how do you know that it is only 2MB? does width*height*4 = 2MB ?

Comment: I have already checked all the links already mentioned in previous posts

Comment: @Selvin  im checking the image size from my sd card, the image is saved correctly in my sdcard but while converting that image into bitmap its having the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm decoding a bitmap. Hope it helps.
Basically I'm not loading the whole picture but just the bitmap for the required size. Otherwise I'm often getting an out of memory error.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String filePath,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    //this avoids memory allocation
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
}


private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: I'm facing problem while resizing the image taken through the android device, im using

    bmp = BitmapsUtiles.getResizedBmp(bmp, AppConstants.DEVICE_WIDTH, AppConstants.DEVICE_HEIGHT);

but still it is not working, can you please point it out what am i doing wrong while resizing???

Comment: Honestly I don't know, I have never used that method. My best guess is that the image is resized AFTER being decoded. Try with this method I wrote to you: decodeSampledBitmapFromResource.